# Prop required or optional based on other boolean props in this case `isLoading` in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I'm trying to create a component in ReactJS and manage prop types using typescript

```
function AccountInfoCard(props: AccountInfoCardProps) {
  const { data, isLoading } = props;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }

  // In this area isLoading must be false and data will be provided correctly.
// no need for optional chaining like this data?.balance
  return <Text>{data.balance}</Text>;
}
```

the current type looks like this

```
type Data = {
  balance: number;
};

type AccountInfoCardProps = {
  isLoading?: boolean;
  data?: Data;
};
```

And i'm expecting that the below requirement to be valid and working as I expected as described in the comment

```
function Test() {
  const dataFromApi = { balance: 100 } satisfies Data;
  const isLoadingApi = 1 + 1 === 2;

  return (
    <>
      {/* // Error: Either isLoading or data must be provided */}
      <AccountInfoCard />
      {/* // Error: Cannot set isLoading to false and not provide data */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={false} />

      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean, data becomes optional */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} />
      {/* // Valid: data is provided then isLoading becomes optional */}
      <AccountInfoCard data={dataFromApi} />
      {/* // Valid: Both isLoading and data are provided */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} data={dataFromApi} />
      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean, data is optional */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={true} />
      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean and data is also provided */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} data={dataFromApi} />
    </>
  );
}
```

what i have tried

```
type AccountInfoCardProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  data?: Data;
} | {
  isLoading?: false;
  data: Data;
};
```

I tried discriminated union like above code but one condition doesn't fulfilled which is

```
 {/* // Error: Cannot set isLoading to false and not provide data */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={false} />
```

suppose to be error but it is not throwing any error

Answer (score 0):

The solution here comes in two parts. First, you need to declare the two possible `AccountInfoCardProps` as a union, as you have done:

```
type AccountInfoCardProps = {
  isLoading?: false;
  data: Data;
} | {
  isLoading: true;
  data?: undefined;
};
```

but after doing that, simply writing `<AccountInfoCard isLoading={someBoolean} />` will **not** work.

This is because in order to let TS pick one of the members of the union, you need to prove whether the boolean is `true` or `false`:

```
// This works
{isLoadingApi && <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} />}
```

The end result looks like this: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBEUYU4BeOAb3LjgCMUAGxQA7NEgBccEQFcQfJFAoBfClVr0AgmjQQZImAEkRmCAGEUUACYAFHGADO7LjzjAHAGQgorwEQHMAfilMIQckCl4rZhQpJhYVOAAfF153Lx8-fykYKBkI12iWYLh9KyRMPyQrFTVMfQxgCBE4bV19IxNzSysACjB7Byk2vQNjUwtrOwhHAEpUuF0RB3hOOCKUABo3T29fALhlZwGZhzU0zDhe9L2s+e5eXiIYGSgWgB4AFSQADxgAPgy+38ADowe8APTfP7-SKHSi8CEQuDGOAwAAW7jgllQOyBWTgIBkK349FCgnC2JEVnWMTgAHdgIJBKS4CcAG7Aco03RQIgYQTUEHkJHSCDSJDVOCmKBwGYwJoiISLdEoPwEwTAADW9AxWI2gRBAmEYiQrmerw+0IBnA2RqEonEykh1th5GUlHqYgVzTg3xWvXuriWJI2ADEcCBNGBgM41sbHZI4ABGAAMqcOcAczHclSQTniKDhIfgN0yAWjsY4ybgAGoU+w2BwAEznOAWt5XVy8d7-buPTgQgBUcFFAFE+dApGPgBjFHjbgdoLSWITifAFGycJzuXAhxCPY9Hu8Rh1xt1rKO+0feIOR+PJ1ApBYRCIIPBwqXduX-GjxeTKVEGk33gDkuXoDY9wPftbzLYFK2SFITx0UZOgmHoFx-NhOAApAjghf4PRgrhh1HZEADUhC5KQ4IJMDd0ZDF+AgCBBFQERtkghRdBAfM5TAH0lRZfdDxvThaIrGM4AAMmkuBkPaMYukmGkJP8bC1MrfDCOIu8yLgSjNSsKRIKxeipTnFo1NJHi+PlRVlRE4iFNQ88VJXFBsPDSMtKvXTSNFQzqLgAAhd90Uw4EqRpSCcS3CAdylJyby4TSpKSJDTyU9DLzUjTv3gmMjg2LyYgjXBfII0Sjz0wKqOMyK6O3cCaUYiK+BYtjRE4uksXs5pHOglKXLPZSMLyzhcnybT-PvCj6pogqmoSlqGVndrOvY6KPJ2bEKXFcyaWSsS0tjDL5KytCL1UpaAny-FJOAYqYlKlhyqjIqr2q+SCNcWYVCAA)

```
function Test() {
  const dataFromApi = { balance: 100 } satisfies Data;
  const isLoadingApi = 1 + 1 === 2;

  return (
    <>
      {/* // Error: Either isLoading or data must be provided */}
      <AccountInfoCard />
      {/* // Error: Cannot set isLoading to false and not provide data */}
      {isLoadingApi || <AccountInfoCard isLoading={false} />}

      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean, data becomes optional */}
      {isLoadingApi && <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} />}
      {/* // Valid: data is provided then isLoading becomes optional */}
      <AccountInfoCard data={dataFromApi} />
      {/* // Valid: Both isLoading and data are provided */}
      {isLoadingApi || <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} data={dataFromApi} />}
      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean, data is optional */}
      <AccountInfoCard isLoading={true} />
      {/* // Valid: isLoading provided with boolean and data is also provided */}
      {isLoadingApi || <AccountInfoCard isLoading={isLoadingApi} data={dataFromApi} />}
    </>
  );
}
```